# Code to take value from file and print average, max and min does not work

Tags: c++

I want to take a large number of different numbers from a file and give back the Average, Max, and Min values to the command line. I came so far, just to loop over the code, not further. I have tried many ways but nothing is working. Can you please guide me?

```cpp
fstream my_file ("values.txt");
vector<int> nums;
double input;
// int max_value {0};
// int min_value {0};
// double average_value = accumulate(nums.begin(), nums.end(), 0) / nums.size();

while (my_file >> input)
{
    nums.push_back(input);
}

for(int num : nums){
    cout << num << endl;
}
```

Comment: You need to do your accumulate after you read your data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks OK, except for you need to `accumulate` *after* you populate your vector:

```
fstream my_file ("values.txt");
vector<int> nums;
double input;

while (my_file >> input )
{
  nums.push_back(input);
}
double average_value = accumulate(nums.begin(), nums.end(), 0) / nums.size();
```

Comment: Just be careful to make sure that a value is actually pushed into the vector, otherwise you would be dividing the result of `accumulate()` by 0, which is *undefined behavior*.

Comment: As for getting the min and max values, look at [`std::minmax_element()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/minmax_element). Though, calculating the average and min/max separately in this manner would require iterating the vector multiple times. So you might consider using a manual loop (or `std::for_each()`) that calculates all 3 values at the same time.

Comment: I will  use std::for_each(), thank you!